# Syncing ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, editing, hosted-feature-layer

I published a WebMap from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online. Going forward, I wish to make all my changes to the data in this map in ArcGIS Pro but I want the changes to be reflected on ArcGIS Online.

I do not want to have to re-publish or re-import data to ArcGIS Online every time changes are made.

Is there a way for me to make changes to the hosted feature services in ArcGIS Pro and have my WebMap on ArcGIS Online automatically update with the changes?

Comment: Will you be editing the data in the web map (e.g., hosted feature services), or changing the web map itself (symbology, popups, etc.)?

Comment: Upload your layers to AGOL, start a new map in ArcPro and add the layers in AGOL back into the map?

Comment: @lambertj I am more concerned about the data at this moment.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes things simpler. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit ArcGIS Online hosted feature services directly in ArcGIS Pro, open the catalog pane and click on Portal at the top. You will then see all data you are the owner of under My Content and things shared with you as part of groups My Groups. After that, simply add the layers you need to update to a map, edit as usual (add or edit features, change attribute values, etc.), then save the edits to commit the changes to the hosted feature service that lives on ArcGIS Online.

These changes will all be reflected in your web map without having to re-publish or overwrite a web layer. In practice, it really doesn't work any differently than editing any other feature layer in ArcGIS Pro. The process is *much* more streamlined than it used to be in ArcMap.

You can also define domains, add fields, or delete fields directly on the hosted feature service in ArcGIS Pro, although some operations on a layer's schema may not be allowed if a layer is actively being used by others or has offline copies in the wild that have been downloaded with Field Maps, etc.

[image]